# How to hide a binding path - Multibinding wpf

Tags: wpf, textblock, multibinding

I have a multibiding issues. I have two binding path in my code but I want to show only one. How I can hide the first one ?

Thanks

```
<TextBlock.Text>
   <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">

                    <Binding Path="PK_ID_Order"/>
                    <Binding Path="Wording" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: I myself, have no idea what you're asking for here.  Can you please explain it further?  You almost make it sound like you don't want a Multibinding at all which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented it's not entirely clear what you're asking for, but i'm going to take a stab and guess you're trying to get a single binding but when you remove one of the binding lines it no longer works. This is because you will need a normal inline/single binding. So here is what you may want.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Wording}"/>
```